# Handle POST request when using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a `NewGroup` component, that makes a POST call to the backend. When call is returned, an action is dispatched accordingly and the app state is updated by the reducer.

BUT! the component `NewGroup` doesn't know id of the newly created entity to look for it in the updated state.

How should I deal with this situation ?

Some code:

This is the reducer:

```
import { FETCH_GROUPS_SUCCESS, FETCH_GROUPS_ERROR, CREATE_GROUP_SUCCESS, CREATE_GROUP_ERROR, DELETE_GROUP, FETCH_GROUP_SUCCESS, FETCH_GROUP_ERROR } from '../actions/creators';

export const FULL_GROUP = 'full_group';
export const SNIPPET_GROUP = 'snippet_group';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: null,
  isLoading: true,
  errorFetching: null
};

export default function(state=INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_GROUPS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        data: _.zipObject(_.map(action.payload, group => group.id),
          _.map(action.payload, group => ({
              data: group,
              isLoading: true,
              errorFetching: null,
              mode: SNIPPET_GROUP
          }))
        ),
        isLoading: false,
        errorFetching: null
      };
    case FETCH_GROUPS_ERROR:
      return {
        data: null,
        isLoading: false,
        errorFetching: action.payload.error
      };
    case CREATE_GROUP_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: {
        data: action.payload,
        isLoading: true,
        errorFetching: null,
        mode: SNIPPET_GROUP
      }};
    case CREATE_GROUP_ERROR:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: {
        data: null,
        isLoading: false,
        errorFetching: action.payload.error
      }};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is the `NewGroup` component:

```
class NewGroup extends Component {

  _onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.createGroup(values);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    //id of the newly created/errored entity on the backend is unknown and there was it cannot be accessed here.
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this._onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field name="name" label="Name" type="text" fieldType="input" component={renderField.bind(this)}/>
          <Field name="description" label="Description" type="text" fieldType="input" component={renderField.bind(this)}/>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/group')}>Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  //a unique id for this form
  form:'NewGroup',
  validators
})(
  connect(null, { createGroup })(NewGroup)
);
```

The fact that this is a `redux-form` is not important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the id in your redux store (say, newlyAddedSomethingId: 'yourID', once it is created, on POST success, dispatch another action (or you could even do it in the same reducer, depends on how you have it setup) to store the id then pass it down to the component. That way your component will re-render once the value in redux store is updated from POST, thus your component knows the ID.

Comment: That practically fixes the issue, but it makes the app state structure look really ugly. I updated my code with some code. Maybe it helps.

Comment: It's not about being ugly, for me even isLoading is ugly, but you need it, and you have to use it. Just use: lastCreatedGroup: [action.payload.id] or something similar. You need to store that ID somewhere, unless, you kinda sort them by date, and get the last added one, but that's not always true if other ppl use/update your data at the same time for example.

Comment: is this prefered over using callbacks ?

Comment: I've discussed with Stephen Grider (https://github.com/StephenGrider) (author of different react/redux courses in Udemy) regarding storing in redux store vs callbacks, and yes, it is preferred over callbacks.

Comment: what if we have several simultaneous POST calls ?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [redux sagas](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga). Using a saga pattern lets you structure your code very nicely.

Comment: If you have several simultaneous POST calls, you store an array of ID's, but again that depends on your use case and how your app is structured.